# How to show/hide element depending on if the value is not undefined on angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have this code to only show the weekly hour if the value is not undefined. However, this `ngIf` check still show `undefined` on the element. I already tried `*ngIf="item.weeklyHour !== undefined"` as well but the `undefined` still shows up. What am I missing?

```
<span class="c-f__weekly-hour" *ngIf="item.weeklyHour">
    {{item.weeklyHour}}
</span>
```

Comment: I guess `item.weeklyHour` is not `undefined` but `"undefined"` (You (accidententaly ?) converted it to string somewhere). That would explain this behavior...

Comment: use <span class="c-f__weekly-hour" *ngIf="item && item.weeklyHour">

Comment: Your question is confusing: "show the weekly hour if the value is not undefined" and " the undefined still shows up"

Answer (score 2):

Use `?` operator

```
<span class="c-f__weekly-hour" *ngIf="item?.weeklyHour">
```

Here is the [PLunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CBP8KRkb1eSZTHebOqqE?p=preview) ,

please open the app.ts file and review the output by commenting and uncommenting the item object.

Comment: Have you tried this? AFAIR safe-nav operator doesn't work with ngIf.

Comment: will you please post the item json object?

Comment: Use this <span class="c-f__weekly-hour" [hidden]="!item?.weeklyHour">

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! It's combination of @Vivek & @n00dl3!
The `json` contains not only the value but also a string so the value was `undefined blabla`. So I updated the `json` and also use the `*ngIf="item?.weeklyHour"`.